# C#: How-To find out if I have the right encoding

Tags: c#, encoding, byte, filestream

I am quite new to files, streams and different codepages.
See this is my problem:

I get text files and some of them have been create with the codepage Windows-1252, some are still IBM850 and sometimes they are UTF8. When I import them, my database shows all kinds of symbols for ä, ö, ü, ß, because I read them with the wrong codepage. only when I import them with the right codepage, everything works fine.

This is what I thought would be could a good approach:

Convert ä, ö, ü, ß to bytes array with a codepage X

eg:

```
byte[] myAeKl = Encoding.GetEncoding("IBM850").GetBytes("ä");

byte[] myAeGr = Encoding.GetEncoding("IBM850").GetBytes("Ä");
```

go through the text files and compare each letters byte array with the ones above. 
if found use that codepage, otherwise try another codepage.

This is what I don't understand:
How can I compare the bytes from the letters in the textfile to the byte arrays of the letters I am looking for.
Eg:

```
if (Textfile.Letter == myAeKl || Textfile.Letter == myAeGr)
...
```

Is there any other way to get the right codepage?
Do I have the right aproach to the solution?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a foolproof method, unfortunately, since a certain stream of bytes can be meaningful in more than one encoding.

One way of doing it is using guesswork and heuristics using other business data. Can you infer the encoding from the filename? From some other metadata, like sender name? If so, try to filter using that.

If not, you can try digging and guessing. If the files can be large, as you say, just peek and bring in a sample of text (say, the first 512 bytes, that should be enough). Do you have any way of guessing what the content can be? Is it free text in English/Hebrew or something like that? If so, look for common words in the 512 byte sample. Do the files contain a fixed format? If so, look for it. Then run these tests on live samples, see the results, tweak the tests, and try again until you have a relatively good chance of recognizing the encoding.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi,

Thank you so much for all your tipps! Now I don't have that kind of info. All the texts in the files are in German, the first positions can be a letter and in others files numbers. That is why I thought my best bet was/is to get everything in bytes and I find those ä,ö,ü and ß somewhere in the text 

Thank you again,

I hope I can find some kind of pattern to match.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to load the file with one encoding and if I encounter unexpected chars, load it with the other one.

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for your quick reply.
well the problem is the files can be big and the import take a certain amout of time and the biggest problem I don't do the import. I just get to programm it :)

Greetz

Comment: "if I encounter" was meant programmatically.